# Dynamic button onclick issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, button

I have the following piece of code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = "button-" + i.ToString();
            btn.Text = "This is button-" + i.ToString();
            btn.Click += (senders, es) => test(i, PlaceHolder1, btn.ID);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
        }

    }

    protected void test(int num, PlaceHolder ph, string btnID)
    {
        Response.Write("The Button clicked on is:  " + num);
    }
```

Now for some reason, which i can't seem to figure out that when ever i click on any of the buttons, the number that is passed which is in variable "num" is always 5. Does anyone know why this happens? Or why it doesn't assign the actual number that it should be to "num"?

Comment: I believe Eric Lippert has a blog about this, but it's because you are using a closure on i when it's finally executed, which will be 5 for all handlers.  Here's the link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: This is a bug in c# compiler with `foreach` loop and same thing is happening here. bug with `foreach` has been fixed in c#5.0. Explanation is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That link is with respect to `foreach` loops.  This is `for` loop, and is unchanged in C# 5.0.  Also, it's not strictly a bug, since it was an intentional design decision on the part of MS.  It's simply an undesirable feature that has since been changed.

Comment: @Servy Exactly. I forgot. Thanks for remembering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're closing over the loop variable.  When you create a lambda that uses `i` it doesn't take a copy of `i` at that point in time, it captures that variable and ensures that the value of `i`, when that lambda is invoked, is what's used.  By the time these anonymous methods are actually executed the loop has long since ended, so the value of `i` at that point in time is `5`.

The fix is simple, rather than having one variable that all 5 buttons reference, ensure each button has their own variable to reference by taking a copy of the value:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var temp = i;
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "button-" + i.ToString();
        btn.Text = "This is button-" + i.ToString();
        btn.Click += (senders, es) => test(temp, PlaceHolder1, btn.ID);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
```

Comment: You beat me to it... (Some more info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).)

Comment: @BradHazelnut This is not a forum. [Is SO a forum?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum)